# Stopping a spinning object with a flexible gripper

Tags: friction, rotation, elasticity, structural-beam

I would like to know how deformation of the contact surface affects friction of a spinning object.

In the image below I have a 2D problem of a spinning circle with two elastic "fingers" pinching it to stop it. [image]

If the two fingers were rigid, then the contact points would be tangent to the circle and then I could use $\mu*N$ to figure out the friction force. However I would like to know how the contact area changes with deformation of the "fingers" and how that affects friction force applied. I'm assuming the fingers are regular elastic beams, with a torque applied at one end to create the closing force.

Comment: Assuming your materials have roughly linear force/displacement curves for low forces, the "fingers" will, at first approximation, have a contact area proportional to the applied force.  This approximation will change fairly quickly, though, since the deformation will not be uniform.

Answer (score 0):

$F=\mu \ N$ is an approximation, but it holds in a wide variety of situations, not just for "rigid" structures.

Is there any reason you think that it is unusable for your elastic setup?  Yes, the contact area will change, but that may not matter.

If it doesn't hold, then there's no simple physics equation to fall back on.  Short of detailed material studies, it would be easier to just do some empirical measurements.  Place a known force on it and measure the deceleration.